# Sin and punishment for using sex toys?

Tags: sex, sin, punishment

What kind of sin is using adult sex toys and what will be punishment in afterlife for that? Is it same as fornication?

Mentioned that for someone who performs masturbation, would it be more punishable for using toys?

Comment: This needs some elaboration: As you could use sex toys to spice up your conjugal sexual intercourse so why should that be sinful?

Comment: @Medi1Saif FYI, the question is in "Unmarried" context. Answer that includes married couples also would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If u're question's related to masturbation. That's a different thing altogether and has nothing to do with sex toys.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD Toys can be used to perform masturbation.

Comment: @HassanTareq So are u asking, if it's okay to masturbate using sex toys? In that case, you need to ask if masturbation is haram or halal. Given the answer is halal, you really can masturbate with any tool even it doesn't go to the extent of raising issue of taswir in islam.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD try to understand "Mentioned that for someone who performs masturbation, would it be more punishable for using toys?"

Answer (score 4):

Well simply said:

There are 2 possible situation that come to mind:

- an unmarried person who uses sex toys this is more or less equal to the case of masturbation, which means that scholars could easily apply qiyas (analogy) to apply the rules or verdicts which apply on masturbation (you will find on the site plenty questions and answers on this topic so this is widely covered).

The fatwa (in Arabic) [#257782](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=257782) on islamweb for example says that using a sex doll for instance is haram (evidence see the verses I'll quote later and it's interpretation) while they hold the opinion that masturbation is allowed in extreme cases to prevent zina.

- a married person who may either use it to spice up his sex life either with a conjugal sexual intercourse this basically is not haram (see details later)
  or to please him or her self here again rules and verdicts for masturbation would apply.

I found a fatwa on islamweb (in Arabic) [#36692](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=36692) saying using a dildo for example is not allowed based on ([23:5-7](http://legacy.quran.com/23/5-7)):

> And **they who guard their private parts**
>   **Except from their wives** or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -
>   But **whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors -**

so this was considered as seeking pleasure beyond the allowed and not guarding their private parts and seeking "foreign" pleasure. However I know of a fatwa from a scholar even allowing this based on the same arguments which are used by those allowing masturbation!

While the use of sex toys in general and role playing (games) for spouses is allowed as far as there's no transgression -as described- and it is a conjugal matter.

So far the legal status:
Note that a punishment can only be applied for something where the Shari'a has prescribed a punishment, on the whole the only sinful act here can be considered as masturbation or equal/analog to masturbation and even if masturbation is considered as a sin by the majority of scholars none of them say it is punishable!
So what ever sinful you do in this matter or commit you must only repent it is still a sin even if it wouldn't take you to a shari'a court unless you've done it in public...

Comment: "a married person who may either use it to spice up his sex life either win a conjugal sexual intercourse this basically is not haram (see details later)
or to please him or her self here again rules and verdicts for masturbation would apply." Can you please provide quote/reference/fatwa this?

Comment: @user34302 if you have read the answer then you should know that this is the point I'm discussing and answering based on the provided sources.

Comment: @Medi1Saif so essentially, just to clarify, a man and women can use sex toys (i.e the ones in the shape of genitalia) so as long as it is used conjugally?