# Regarding the hadith below, and the ayah [23:5-7]

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, hadith-interpretation, masturbation, surah

this hadith states:

> “Whatever Allah has permitted in His Book is halal, whatever He has forbidden is haram, and whatever He was silent about is pardoned, so accept the pardon of Allah, for Allah was not forgetful."
>
> Then he recited this verse: ‘and your Lord is never forgetful’ [Maryam 19:64].” This hadith was classed as sahih by Shaykh al-Albaani (may Allah have mercy on him) in al-Silsilah al-Saheehah (5/325), and classed as hasan on p. 14 of Ghaayat al-Maraam.

and regarding the ayah:

> "And they who guard their private parts Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors." [23:5-7]

isn't it possible that when Allah (SWT) said nothing about masturbation it means that he is gonna pardon the act of masturbation because it never EXPLICITLY states masturbation, just actions with another person.

Comment: "Whoever seeks beyond that" addresses any other option see for example [Sin and punishment for using sex toys?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43965/sin-and-punishment-for-using-sex-toys/43969#43969) for an interpretation

Answer (score 1):

You're readings your own words into the hadith. It nowhere says that haram thing needs to be explicitly named, only that if something is not forbidden (directly or indirectly in any way at all) then you can hope for Allah's pardon. Masturbation is not directly named but it is rationally included in: "**But whoever seeks beyond that**".

Take this example. You make an announcement:  "No one should call me after 8 pm"
And I call you and say: "Hey, you didn't explicitly say that *Ryan* shouldn't call you". What will be youre response?
You will say: Ryan is included in your statment: "No one"

Comment: We can also say that Allah (SWT) is talking about intimacy with other people...
and not with yourself

Comment: but this is also correct i cant argue with this... so yeah you're right (sorry for second comment cannot seem to edit first comment)

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where everything is banned except what is specifically allowed. The ayah is clear about this:

> "And they who guard their private parts Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed -**But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors.**

Allah bans explicitly everything except wives or those that their right hand possesses. Allah is not silent about it, so it is not pardoned.

Answer (score 0):

Asalam u alikum,

you are right, masturbation has not been explicitly mentioned in the Quran, however you have to take into consideration the process of this case. You are, in nearly all situations, going to require an image/video, classed as material, to do such act. Pornography is haram material, which is why it is haram to watch it. It might be “makruh” (disliked) however it isn’t recommended.

Comment: Yeah but it's possible to masturbate without the images/videos. Allah allowed for us to think about bad things as long as it's not taking into action and it is also makruh (disliked) to think about bad things because it might lead to the action of said sinful thing. But, nonetheless it is permissible.